# React JS compiles but does not show content on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working my way through a project built using ReactJS, and I have come across situations where my code compiles just fine, but nothing displays when I navigate to localhost.

My program is a basically a "Hello World" application that works as expected *until* I import the following:

```
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
```

I have added react-bootstrap as a dependency, and I am able to see the `Row` class in `node_modules`, but whenever this line is included in my program nothing displays on the page, and there are no console or compilation errors to be found. However, if I remove this line, everything renders as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you imported Bootstrap css files?

Comment: Can you share the whole file? Or at least where you're using `Row` and all your imports?

Comment: Not much to go on here. Maybe share the compiler output in case there's something you're not noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap';` and confirm you have react-bootstrap installed by looking at your package.json file.